# Proving the statement "$l^1$ is complete." differently.

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I want to prove $l^1$ is complete. I want to prove that any Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ is Convergent to $(y)$ whose $y_i$ is the limit of the sequence $x_{(n,i)}$  . I want to prove this part first then I would show that $||y||$ is bounded not the other way around.

Can anyone please help me to proceed? I am really having 
 trouble to visualize that the Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$  converges to $(y)$.

Comment: if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, then so are the coordinate sequences $(x^{(j)}_n)$. So if your scalar field is complete, you get a candidate for the limit sequence.

Comment: Yea I understood up to the limit point convergence. I have written this in my question. $(y)$ is that sequence. But I have to prove that $(x_n)$ converges to $(y)$.@Matematleta

Comment: Then, I am not sure what you are asking but I have posted a sketch of a proof. If it is not what you are looking for, let me know and I will be happy to delete it.

Comment: Please show me how the Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $y$.@Matematleta

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: picking up from our comments, we have $x^{(j)}_n\to y_j$ for each $j\in \mathbb N$.

Step $1$: show that $y=(y_j)\in \ell^1:$

$\|y\|:=\lim_{J\to \infty}\sum^J_{j=1}|y_j|=\lim_{J\to \infty}(\sum^J_{j=1}\lim_{n\to \infty}|x^{(j)}_n|)=\lim_{J\to \infty}\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sum^J_{j=1}|x^{(j)}_n|).$

Now, $\sum^J_{j=1}|x^{(j)}_n|\le \sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|x^{(j)}_n|=\|x_n\|\le M<\infty $ because the original sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, hence bounded. So,

$\|y\|\le \lim_{n\to \infty}M=M.$

Step $2:$ Prove that $\|x_n-y\|\to 0:$

Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose an integer $N$ such that $l,n>N\Rightarrow \|x_l-x_n\|<\epsilon.$

Then, $\sum^J_{j=1}|x_n^{(j)}-x_l^{(j)}|\le \sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|x_n^{(j)}-x_l^{(j)}|=\|x_n-x_l\|<\epsilon.$

I'll leave the rest to you: keep $n>N$, fix $J$ and let $l\to \infty.$ Finally, let $J\to \infty.$

Comment: I have problem in the second part. Please complete it. @Matematleta

Comment: And  I have seen this proof earlier. It is kind of escaping proof. It can not be visualized.@Matematleta

Comment: The Cauchy criterion? What? All I am doing is proving that the logical candidate for the limit of the $(x_n)$ is indeed the limit. To do this, you need to show two things 1). it's in $\ell^1$. and 2) the sequence $(x_n)$ actually converges to it. I think my sketch is a good roadmap. Suggestion: write the sequence $(x_n)$ in matrix form to see what is going on. The fact that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in each coordinate is really all you need to know.

Comment: without using limit can you show it ?@Matematleta

Comment: Your answer helped me to understand what I wanted to understand.@Matematleta

Comment: Glad to help---